# Why is the hip pouch upgrade missing from the west storage room?

Tags: resident-evil-2-2019

I played the Resident Evil 2 - 1 shot demo and near the end you get a hip pouch upgrade in the West Storage Room on Level 3 of the police station.

When I got the full game I started with Clare and when I got to the same point the hip pouch upgrade wasn't there. I read that the locations of items was different in each scenario so I didn't think much of it at the time.

When I completed the game I had found 5 out of the 6 hip pouches and was curious about the one I missed as I generally cleared all rooms i.e they were blue on the map, and explored thoroughly.

Turns out every guide I looked at shows that the hip pouch should have been in the same location as the demo, on the bench in the West Storage Room on Level 3. I have loaded an old save and gone to look for the hip pouch in the west storage room but it is definitely not there.

Any ideas why the hip pouch missing, is it a glitch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that not all of the hip pouch upgrades are available when playing on Hardcore difficulty.

You actually only get 3 upgrades of 2 slots each on Hardcore.

To get all the hip pouches and associated trophy/achievement for maxing out your inventory space you need to play on standard difficulty or lower.